# asp.net reading client side dropdown values in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, client-side

So I have two dropdown controls, the second one (the data comes from a JSON file) is filled depending on the value of the first dropdown:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="task1DD"/>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="task2DD"/>
```

In the code behind I used an override render method to accept the client's data:

```
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(task2DD.UniqueID,"text_from_dd");
        ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(task2DD.UniqueID,"text_from_dd");
        ...
        base.Render(writer);
    }
```

Now when I tried to read the value from the second Dropdown:

```
task2DD.Text
```

I don't get nothing, like the variable is empty. Are there other steps that I need to do in order to read the data that was filled in the client?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to get the display text of what is selected

```
task2DD.SelectedItem.Text;
```

and the following to get the value

```
task2DD.SelectedValue;
```